# How do I make a rhandsontable reactive on both data upload as well as user edits?

Tags: r, shiny, rhandsontable

In my application, I want to allow the user to upload a CSV file and choose a specific set of columns for further treatment.

To do this, I obtain the column names from the uploaded file and display a checkbox against each column name using rhandsontable. I need to store the details of which columns should be treated.

My problem is that I am able to solve the individual problems in the question. I know how to store the rhandsontable in the back-end if an edit is made (as described [here](http://stla.github.io/stlapblog/posts/shiny_editTable.html)). In the example app below, I know how to update the display of the column names and checkboxes if new data is uploaded.

However, I am unable to solve the problem of doing both - that is to store the list of columns in the back-end when an user-edit is made while also allowing it to be reset completely if new data is uploaded.

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)

dataTabUI <- function(id, i, od, os) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(i,
          column(6, tableOutput(od)),
          column(6, rHandsontableOutput(os)))
}

dataTab <- function(input, output, session) {

}

csvFileInput <- function(id, label = "CSV file") {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    fileInput(ns("file"), label)
  )
}

csvFile <- function(input, output, session) {
  userFile <- reactive({
    validate(need(input$file, message = FALSE))
    input$file
  })
  dataframe <- reactive({
    df <- read.csv(
      userFile()$datapath,
      header = TRUE
    )
  })
  dataframe
}

ui <- shinyUI(
  navbarPage(
    "My Application",
    tabPanel(
      "File Upload",
      dataTabUI("tab1", csvFileInput("datafile", "Upload CSV"),
                "data", "vars")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  dataframe <- callModule(csvFile, "datafile")
  output$data <- renderTable({
    head(dataframe(), n = 10L)
  })
  output$vars <- renderRHandsontable({
    df <- dataframe()
    cnames <- colnames(df)
    ctypes <- vapply(cnames, function(cname) {
      class(df[[cname]])
    }, character(1))
    datavars <- data.frame(cnames = cnames, ctypes = ctypes,
                           treat = rep(TRUE, length(cnames)),
                           stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    rhandsontable(datavars)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to a helpful suggestion in [RStudio Community](https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-do-i-make-a-rhandsontable-reactive-on-both-data-upload-as-well-as-user-edits/22814), I am able to answer my own question.

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)

dataTabUI <- function(id, i, od, os) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(i,
          column(6, tableOutput(od)),
          column(6, rHandsontableOutput(os)))
}

dataTab <- function(input, output, session) {

}

csvFileInput <- function(id, label = "CSV file") {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    fileInput(ns("file"), label)
  )
}

csvFile <- function(input, output, session) {
  userFile <- reactive({
    validate(need(input$file, message = FALSE))
    input$file
  })
  dataframe <- reactive({
    df <- read.csv(
      userFile()$datapath,
      header = TRUE
    )
  })
  dataframe
}

ui <- shinyUI(
  navbarPage(
    "My Application",
    tabPanel(
      "File Upload",
      dataTabUI("tab1", csvFileInput("datafile", "Upload CSV"),
                "data", "vars")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  dataframe <- callModule(csvFile, "datafile")
  output$data <- renderTable({
    head(dataframe(), n = 10L)
  })

  dfvars <- reactive({
    df <- dataframe()
    cnames <- colnames(df)
    ivars <- input$vars
    if (length(ivars) > 0) {
      odf <- hot_to_r(ivars)
      ocnames <- odf$cnames
      if (!all(vapply(ocnames, function(x) {
        x %in% cnames
      }, logical(1)))) {
        ctypes <- vapply(cnames, function(cname) {
          class(df[[cname]])
        }, character(1))
        datavars <- data.frame(cnames = cnames, ctypes = ctypes,
                               treat = rep(TRUE, length(cnames)),
                               stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
      } else {
        datavars <- odf
      }
    } else {
      ctypes <- vapply(cnames, function(cname) {
        class(df[[cname]])
      }, character(1))
      datavars <- data.frame(cnames = cnames, ctypes = ctypes,
                             treat = rep(TRUE, length(cnames)),
                             stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    }
    datavars
  })

  output$vars <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(dfvars())
  })

  observe({
    print(dfvars())
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```